# Textbox DataBinding to a property of another class

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I got a little problem with binding a property of another class to my `TextBox`.

For example this is the code (`Person` is just a sample class):

```
public class wndMain : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _Max;
    public Person Max
    {
        get
        {
            return _Max;
        }
        set
        {
            _Max = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Max");
        }
    }

    public wndMain()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize()
    {
        Max = new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "Max",
            LastName = "Mustermann",
            Age = 21
        };
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string sPropertyName = null)
    {
        if(this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(sPropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And now I want to bind the first name of the person object instance to my `TextBox`, the binding would look like that:

```
"{Binding Path=Max.FirstName, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

But nothing happens - I also included the `INotifyPropertyChanged` to the `person` class but this didn't help either.

Do you got any advice?

Comment: Did you set the `DataContext` in your XAML? If not, add `DataContext = this;` to the `wndMain()` constructor.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! I just added `DataContext = this;` to the constructor of my wndMain class and it worked! Thank you very much @FrankM